# Android How to create a recurring task that will happen every friday?

Tags: android, calendar, recurring, recurring-events

My problem is that I want the application to download some information from my database every week. This is like a new promotion every week and will be updated on the database every Friday.

I know how to check what day of the week it is using the calendar.

But I don't know how to find out when the next occurring Friday will be.

Is it possible to do or should I just make it a weekly check starting the day the application was installed?

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: Use the alarm service !

Comment: Can you use the alarm serve to not start the activity but to insure it will do it when the activity is next opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the timestamp of your last update in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) with [`INTERVAL_DAY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_DAY). When it wakes up your app, check if it's Friday, or has been more than 156 hours since the last update. If it is, run your updates.

Alternatively, check the last update time when launching, and if it's been more than a x days since the last update, update then.

Comment: it is not so simple as you think ... all alarms are ripped after each boot ... thats why he should use cwac-wakeful :) ... check: `AlarmManager: Making the Services Run On
Time` in http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/wakeful.pdf

Comment: It's pretty common to set the alarm on `BOOT_COMPLETED`. `cwac-wakeful` is excellent for what it is designed to do, but it's overkill for weekly updates. For those, the exact time isn't necessary, and the inexact-repeating alarm will be perfect fit. In fact, `cwac-wakeful` might even impact the battery negatively.

Comment: I would prefer not to wake the device but only check when the application is opened where it would check if it has passed the last Friday that it has kept a record of.

Comment: The device doesn't wake up if you use AlarmManager with an inexact repeating alarm. It just fires when the device is awake already. Of course, you could also just check on launching your app how long it has been since the last update.